# Angular 2: Passing multiple inputs and comparing to respective properties in JSON file and retrieving appopriate objects

Tags: angular, observable, angular-http, angular-filters

I have multiple inputs in a form as you can see some of them below. These are search inputs.
[image: Multiple inputs in a form]

In this application, I want to retrieve contracts with the appropriate properties in the JSON file matching the search.

This is what I currently have:

 
HTML:

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" name="contractFirmName" 
[(ngModel)]="cFirmName">
```

Component.ts

```
searchResultsWithFirmName() {
    this.contractDataService
    .getContract(this.cFirmName)
    .subscribe(
        (contracts) => {
            this.contracts = contracts;
        }
    )
}
```

contractDataService

```
getContract(cFirmName: string): Observable<Contract[]> {
    return this.api.getContract(cFirmName);
}
```

APIService

```
getContract(cFirmName: string) {
    return this.http
      .get(API_URL + '/contracts')
      .map(response => {
        const contracts = response.json();
        return contracts.filter(
          contract => contract.contractFirmName.includes(cFirmName)
        );
      }).catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

In this case, I am able to filter for the first input, Contract Firm Name. However, there will be lots of other use cases when different inputs are used.

For example:
1. A user searches for a Contract with a Firm Name AND Contract Type.
2. A user searches for a Contract using only Contract Type.

I have thought about passing in each input as a parameter, but thought it would be not good code to keep passing in individual inputs as it'd be too long. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pass an object instead of individual model property?

To pass multiple inputs, first prepare an object composing of all `ngModel` values inside your component. You can then pass this to service.

Of course, you should modify your service to accommodate the change.

```
getContract(inputObj: {}): Observable<Contract[]> {
    return this.api.getContract(inputObj);
}
```

In your component you can write a common function which will fetch all the input values from `ngModel` to prepare your object.

component.ts -- just an example

```
searchResults() {
  let inputObj = {
        firmName : cFirmName,
        firmType : cFirmType,
     }
    this.contractDataService
    .getContract(inputObj)
    .subscribe(
        (contracts) => {
            this.contracts = contracts;
        }
    )
}
```